Site goes back a page when exiting iframe s3 video on iphone
Whenever I click on the X on top left to close the full-screen video the website goes back a page. This behavior occurs only on an iphone and not on android or browser on laptop (I haven't tested a macbook). The relevant div section of code:
<div class="container-fluid first-cont">
   <div class="container columns"> 
       <div class="iframe-container">
           <iframe src="{{ user.video_url }}" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

How can i solve this? The headers in the html if they could be causing this effect:
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


Let me know if any more information is required to answer, as I am not exactly proficient in web development.

try to create a custom button for close, and try to set a click function in this button with event.preventDefault for prevent default actions in web browser. But if you prefer hidden the original iframe close button try to get id or class name with web browser inspector for hidden her.
